# How to set environmental variables on aws ec2 mern app deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mern

I want to deploy my mern app in aws ec2 instance, I did clone my folder into the instance but I don't know how to set the env variables. I tried to create an .env file and store my varibles, but that didn't work either. So is there any other method to do the same or should I use any other aws service to store my env variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Param Store` or you could add the environment variable on the instance's `/home/ec2-user/.bashrc`

You could also do this using `User Data` when you launch the instance.

```
[ec2-user@ ~]$ cat /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
export ENV1=TestEnv1
export ENV2=TestEnv2
```

you need to execute the following to set the variable

```
source /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
```

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-42-105 ~]$ echo $ENV1
TestEnv1
```

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-42-105 ~]$ echo $ENV2
TestEnv2
```